# Android doesn't feel as responsive as iOS?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g, ios

I have a Moto G 2 on Lollipop and it doesn't feel as fast as like say an iPhone 5C. I know that it should be the same,  as they have similar specs,  but why does Lollipop feel so slow compared to iOS? Everything just feels snappier on iPhone. I think part of it is that iOS opens apps immediately then loads,  but android loads the app,  then opens it. How do I make my phone feel more responsive? It is rooted.

Comment: See if changing Window, Transition and Animator duration scale to a low value would help you here. They are under Developer options. See [how to enable the Developer options](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-debugging/info), if needed.